# How do you find betweennes centrality from igraph and what does the output number mean?

Tags: r, igraph

Hi so bascially lets say I have a network(A) and I want to find the betweeness centrality of it.

I used: `centr_betw(graph, directed = FALSE, normalized = TRUE)`
This returned every node with the value:

```
[1] 1.827102e+04 3.554450e+04 5.000000e-01 9.524383e+04
[5] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.078184e+05 4.768125e+04
```

I really want to know what these numbers mean.

It also shows the between centralization of the whole network and a max value. Lets say the network(A) as a whole has a betweenness centrality of **0.04**. What can you say about this network(A) when it is compared to a random network with a betweeness centrality of **0.001**?

MUCH THANKS GUYS

Comment: Does my answer answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

Quite a bit of information can be found simply if you type `?centr_betw`. In particular, `centr_betw` returns a list of three components: `res`, `centralization`, `theoretical_max`.

Each element of `res` is the betweenness centrality of a corresponding vertex *i* computed in [this manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality#Definition). Specifically, given a shortest path between some vertices *j* and *k* (not equal to *i*), *i* is considered to be more central if this shortest path includes *i*. Going over all possible pairs of *j* and *k* we can find this betweenness centrality of *i*.

Further, `centralization` and `theoretical_max` concern the [Freeman centralization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Freeman_Centralization). `centralization` is C_x, which measures how central network's most central vertex is in relation to how central all the other vertices are. `theoretical_max` is the denominator of C_x providing the maximal possible value of the numerator across all networks with the same number of vertices.

So, if network A has Freeman centralization 0.04 and network B has 0.001, then we may say that the most central vertex of A is significantly more central than the most central vertex of B. If B is random (i.e., Erdos-Renyi), then that makes sense, because in a big enough network all vertices should play pretty similar role.